# What does if(false){some code} mean in java

Tags: java, if-statement

Java code

```
if(x == null){
 //some code
}
if(false){
 //some code
}
```

when is `if(false){code}` executed?

Comment: What a question... Of course the answer is: Never

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is never executed. Sometimes people do it when they have some old code they want to remember, or some new code that should not yet be used. like

```
if(false){fancyNewFunction();}
```

(as far as i'm concerned, this is bad form and you should not do it, but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen ;)  )

Comment: It's more than that the code does not execute. The byte code is not put in the class by the compiler so the entire `if` statement is removed so there are no cycles spent on even testing `false`.

Comment: If the test was done it would be even worse, but still you are using some feature of the compiler to save something that is basically a comment. If you want to comment something, make it a comment. it's much more readable.

Comment: It's so SonarQube has something to report on... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

This could also be a common way to emulate macro preprocessor directives like #ifdefine. Some people use it to enable or disable logging.

For instance the following code:

```
public class Sample{

    private static final boolean LOG_ENABLED = true;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        if(LOG_ENABLED){
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the following bytecodes:

```
public class Sample extends java.lang.Object{
public Sample();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   ldc #3; //String Hello World
   5:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8:   return

}
```

If you disable the flag, you get this bytecodes:

```
public class Sample extends java.lang.Object{
public Sample();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   return

}
```

As you can see, no bytecodes were generated for the second case in the main method. So, if you disable logging and recompile the code, you improve underlying bytecodes.

Comment: +1. The other answers just stating it "will never execute" are not fully correct. The code is physically removed by the compiler and is part of the Java compiler specification.

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
if (false)
{
   doSomething();
}
```

on occasion to prevent execution of `doSomething()`.

It may be better/clearer to do this:

```
final static private boolean ENABLE_WOLZOPPERY = false;

if (ENABLE_WOLZOPPERY)
{
   wolzopp1();
}
blah_blah_blah();
if (ENABLE_WOLZOPPERY)
{
   wolzopp2();
}
```

so that a single constant can enable/disable the behavior of more than one block in a named fashion.

Comment: Why not just comment it out instead of using if(false)?

Comment: @Fortega because this pattern can be used to enable / disable multiple code blocks by editing a single line (+1 to the answer)

Comment: It's more than that the code does not execute. The byte code is not put in the class by the compiler so the entire `if` statement is removed so there are no cycles spent on even testing `false`.

Comment: @Kevin: that too. I'm so used to the remove-never-executed-code-at-compile-time behavior that I forget to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The code in if condition executes when the condition becomes ***true*** now in `if(false)` the condition is always ***false*** so code in if will never execute.

```
if(false){

// This code will be dead code and will never execute.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `code` in `if(false) { code }` will **never** be executed.

It is a common way to "comment out" code that should not be running (usually debugging code or test code). It's not really the best style, in my opinion, but it's a quite common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Code like this will never execute. Remove it. Do not comment it out. It is just clutter that will confuse someone who has to maintain it later on. If you need to get it back, go to your version control system.

Comment: It's more than that the code does not execute. The byte code is not put in the class by the compiler so the entire `if` statement is removed so there are no cycles spent on even testing `false`. So there is additional reason for this when using a constant; particularly for special debugging code in loops that require high-performance.

Comment: It still adds cruft to the code and should be removed. It is distracting.

Answer (score 0):

`code` is never executed, and probably will be eliminated from the byte code. *However* the snippet will be syntax-checked at build time, so there are sometimes good reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

the code inside the if will never be executed, the code might as well just be commented code out

Comment: Agreed - it's extremely annoying having to dig through mounds of half-commented out functions trying to work out what it's actually doing. It's unfortunate that some people like to use comments as a form of source control.

Comment: I wasn't saying I would comment out the code, just pointing out that if(false) basically has the same affect as commenting out

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal code, I have never used constructs liked this. Maybe a lousy way to comment out some code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be convenient if you are stepping through code in the debugger.

If you have code that you only want executed while it is being 'supervised' i.e. you're using the debugger and actively setting the next executable step in the code to be inside the `if (false)` block.  Normally, when the code is run it will be skipped.

There's no real reason for this to be in production code though.

Answer (score 0):

`if (false)` means peace of code which is never executed. If some of your code is unused you should remove it.

The only reason for using the code is debug purpose but I think it isn't good idea. Nowadays when IDE exists we can select block of code and press some shortcut to make multilines comments (for Eclipse CTRL + /).

You should never commit this code because can cause many problems:

- It's hard to notice that this peace of code never be executed
- We still must maintenance this code.
- We cannot make test coverage for this

Comment: So how would you 'make test coverage' for that piece of code?

Comment: You cannot prepare any test for peace of code inside if. It's mean that what you have inside if(false) is never tested

Answer (score 0):

I use `if(false)` when I use `goto` statement, to go there & execute some code not done otherwise and continue with rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping a code into `if(false)` block is just for author's referral.

Of course the code will never be executed but it holds instructions that could be executed otherwise. Saying today I'm writing a code and have an idea of something else that could be helpful in future days but still need clear ideas of how I could process. Instead of just writing comments or comment the code, I put it into that block.

It's not a good practice though. But doesn't harm.